# Coupon code is not working for specific product in magento1.9

Tags: coupon

I have added a coupon code for a specific product using product SKU.But it's not applying in front end it shows this is not a valid coupon code.I checked in Core my coupon code is not adding in quote remaining coupons added correctly but this only specific coupon based on SKU is not adding tell me any solution.

```
$this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode($isCodeLengthValid ? $couponCode : '')
            ->collectTotals()
            ->save();
```

Comment: did you checked the matching condition for coupon code ?

Comment: Yes I have added with matching condition for that product using the SKU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following Possible issue.

1 Maybe some other rule already applied which have higher priority then coupon code. Please change priority and try again.

2 Maybe some condition are not satisfied. Please re check and try again

Or

3 Maybe it's because of [known bug](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/67) in Magento CE 1.9 .

Issue state that

When creating a shopping cart price rule in Magento CE 1.9 and using 'Stop Further Rules Processing', the logic has been changed since 1.8 CE and is now flawed. This flawed logic now stops rules being applied correcty with more than one product in the cart and doesn't consider 'Stop Further Rules Processing' at the item level. This means that you get incorrect discount amounts applied as per the bug report here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/67

https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix